# How to make kubernetes cronjob to identify ssh key from a folder

Tags: kubernetes, scp, kubernetes-cronjob

I have create cron job in kubernetes and I have ssh key in one of  pod directory. when I am executing from command line its working fine, but when I am manually triggered , cron job is not recognizing .ssh folder .

```
scp -i  /srv/batch/source/.ssh/id_rsa   user@server:/home/data/openings.csv  /srv/batch/source
```

[image]

Comment: you can see the reason if you run the scp with -v option. Can you post it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you log into a remote host from your container, the remote host key is  unknown to your SSH client inside the container

usually, you're asked to confirm its fingerprint:

```
The authenticity of host ***** can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is *****.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

But as there is no interactive shell, the SSH client fails.

Two solutions:

- add the host key in the file `~/.ssh/known_hosts` in the container
- disable host key check (**Dangerous as no remote host authentication is performed**)

  `ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@host`